# Operator Precedence using double brackets in JS

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

I got this code:

```js
let x = -2;
let ex = ((x += 10) > ++x) * 2;
console.log(ex);
```

Trying to figure out why the output in the console here is 0, while I think it should be 2? Here's my reasoning behind it:

When I reference the order of precedence in MDN, I also need to account for double brackets here. This means this is how I prioritized my actions:

1. `+=` (in double brackets) // I get a value 8
2. `++` (according to the second highest priority in a global bracket) // I get -1
3. `>` (the third priority) // at this point I'm comparing 8 against -1 (8 > -1) = true, meaning the value now becomes 1
4. `*` (last one) // 1 * 2 = 2

Above is my own thought process. Can you please explain why I should get 0 in the end? Intuitively, it means the boolean value in brackets needs to be `false`, to be converted to `0`. And then `0 * 2 = 0`.

Thanks.

Comment: `x+=10` mutates `x` before `++x` does.

Comment: I see now! x has changed to 8 after the first action. and we use 8, not -2, moving forward. thanks!

Comment: Operator precedence and evaluation order are two separate things. Compare `(++x < (x += 10)) * 2;`, which uses the same precedence rules but has different evaluation order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense if you look at it one expression at a time:

```js
let x = -2;
// x = -2

let ex = (
  ( x+= 10)
  // x = 8 (which is what this expression returns)
  >
  ++x
  // x = 9 (which is what this expression returns)
) * 2:

// In other words:
let ex = (8 > 9) * 2;
// which results in 0
```

Operator precedence matters, yes, but that doesn't mean the VM will suddenly pre-calculate an expression on the right-hand side of `>`. When evaluating binary operator expressions, it will always evaluate the left-hand side, then the right-hand side. *(with the exception of e.g. `&&` where the right-hand side might be skipped)*.

Comment: thanks kelvin! im a little confused by the flow here now - `(++x < (x += 10)) * 2`. why would we be getting 0 instead of 2?

Comment: We end up with `(-1 < (x = -1 + 10)) * 2` which is `(-1 < 9) * 2` (with `x==9`) so again, we get `false * 2` which is 0.

Comment: sorry, stupid question.. but this is the part i don't fully get // how come -1 < 9 returns `false` in the first place?

Comment: @chessplayer No I'm the stupid one here, I thought it was still using `>`. I ran your code with the `<` just now, and it does actually result in 2, which is the result of `true * 2`.